# get number after matching string in ruby with regex

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I'm trying to get the number of tracking_number from the string.

```
string = '{:rate_type=>"PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE", :rated_weight_method=>"ACTUAL", tracking_number=>"795856589804"}, :group_number=>"0", :package_rating=>{:actual_rate_type=>"PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE", :package_rate_details=>{:rate_type=>"PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE", :rated_weight_method=>"ACTUAL", :minimum_charge_type=>"CUSTOMER_FREIGHT_WEIGHT", :billing_weight=>{:units=>"LB", :value=>"1.0"}}'
```

I have tried `/tracking_number=>['"]((.*?)['"])*/` but getting all the string after the match.

Can anybody help me on this.

I have tried this at https://rubular.com/r/ZcmJinTHDQSDsZ

Output I want is `795856589804`

Comment: Where does that string come from? It looks like a Ruby hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `*` from end of your regex. This is the reason you are getting all the string after match.

And If you want to get just the number part then use this regex.

```
/tracking_number=>"(\d+)"/
```